# (electron & nodejs) "TypeError: globalDate is not a constructor" when with require('mssql')

Tags: node.js

I'm working on an Electron app and we are visualizing SQL data. I have used `'mssql'` a while ago and there were no problems but now I am getting a *strange* error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: globalDate is not a constructor
    at Object../node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/lib/data-types/date.js (index.js:228312)
    at __webpack_require__ (index.js:833)
    at fn (index.js:130)
    at Object../node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/lib/data-type.js (index.js:227864)
    at __webpack_require__ (index.js:833)
    at fn (index.js:130)
    at Object../node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/lib/request.js (index.js:232937)
    at __webpack_require__ (index.js:833)
    at fn (index.js:130)
    at Object../node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js (index.js:225160)
```

that occurs only when I create a variable (it will error when the method is called):

`const sql = require("mssql");`

or (it will error when the app starts) if I even just try:

`import * as sql from 'mssql'`

Searching around for globalDate has been futile and miserable. I've tried `npm uninstall` with `mssql` and `tedious` as well as  Any suggestions?

Comment: are there any changes for mssql in the package-lock.json ?